# Send mail SMTP GMail and PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have problem about sending mails with Google SMTP and latest version of PHPMailer. Here are a lot of questions, but the answers doesn't work for me.
I am using free hosting with free subdomain `000webhost`.
This is my standard PHP code for sending email from `PHPMailer` docs:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'GMAIL EMAIL ACCOUNT';
$mail->Password = 'MY PASSWORD FOR GMAIL EMAIL ACCOUNT';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tlc';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
$mail->setFrom('EMAIL ADDRESS', 'EXAMPLE');
$mail->addAddress('ADDRESS TO SEND', 'From contact form');

$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

and I get this error:

> .... 2017-06-03 15:15:33  SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>                                         535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 203sm11822739ywk.62 - gsmtp
>   2017-06-03 15:15:33   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
>                                         535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 203sm11822739ywk.62 - gsmtp
>   2017-06-03 15:15:33 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
>   .....

I see same error if I use `ssl` with port `465`.

In my `Gmail` email account 2-factory authentication is `OFF` and `Allow less secure apps` is `ON`.

I really don't know what to do.

Comment: No such setting as `tlc` for `SMTPSecure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way with creating `Google App Password` and use it instead `Gmail` account password:

```
$mail->Password = 'GOOGLE APP PASSWORD';
```

To create an app password you need to set `Two factory authentication`: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en, then you can create app password  - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: I created an app password and it's still failing

Comment: @Scott, strange, what's the response ?

Comment: I gave up on it when I learned I could use Amazon SES if I just authorize/confirm the 'from' addresses we use.  Then I just needed to configure sendmail (postfix) to relay through the SES and local php can use local sendmail or php builtin mail to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into your Google account at https://myaccount.google.com
2. Click on "Security" in the left-hand menu.
3. Scroll down to the "Less secure app access" section.

   Click "Turn on access (not recommended)".

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/23875320?hl=en